# Android/React Native crashing with react-native-ble-manager on one phone, but not other

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, react-native-ble-manager

So I'm running into an issue where I am getting an app crashing on one phone (Pixel 6 Android 13), but not an Android 11 phone when running `BLEManager.scan`.

Here are the permissions being used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION " />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

And in the app am running

```
PermissionsAndroid.request(
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
)
```

Guessing this is an android version issue, but not sure as this is not specified in docs.

**Answer:**

I needed to request these permissions at runtime post Android 12. I ran into issues because my version of react-native/@types/react-native was outdated and didn't contain the `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` and `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` permissions. I bumped the version up past `react-native@0.67` and then could request these permissions at runtime.

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from "react-native"

await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
     PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
     PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
     PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
])
```

Previously I was only requesting

```
PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
)
```

Comment: Have you tried other Android 13 devices ?

Comment: For Android >= 12, the new Bluetooth permissions are permissions that must be requested at runtime. So similar to how older versions used the location permission.

Comment: Yep it was this, just there wasn't any updated documentation on this for the BLE Manager specifically. Thanks @Emil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

I needed to request these permissions at runtime post Android 12. I ran into issues because my version of react-native/@types/react-native was outdated and didn't contain the `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` and `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` permissions. I bumped the version up past `react-native@0.67` and then could request these permissions at runtime.

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from "react-native"

await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
     PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
     PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
     PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
])
```

Previously I was only requesting

```
PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
)
```